# Checking for double email addresses which are encrypted in the database

Tags: security, validation, encryption

People can register for a newsletter on my website.
Their email address and other personal information will be encrypted in the database.

Now for that registration form I'd like to check if the newly inputted email address is already in my database, but as all emails are encrypted, I can't really check unless I loop through every possible email address, decrypt it and see if it matches the newly inputted email? Is that correct? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the same encryption key all the time, you can simply search for the encrypted version. If you do not, you can still store a hash of the addresses additionally and compare against that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, when I save an encrypted version of an email address, I always see another value in my email address database field. So I can't really search for the encrypted version? I thought only hashed versions of an email address will always give the same value?

Comment: I don’t know what you use to encrypt. If you use a symmetric cipher with a fixed key, you get the same encrypted value. But as I said, if that is not the case, you can still add a field with a hash and only decrypt and check the addresses where the hash matches.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple thought: create a table with a md5 hash of the mail and compare this in your SQL WHERE clause? Not sure if this is very effective..