# How to check if an email address exists in a table, which contains encrypted email addresses

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have a table which contains encrypted email addresses of users. When a new user signs up, I want to check if the email address entered already exists in the table. I use the `openssl_encrypt` function in php to encrypt every email address. Since the function returns a different encrypted value even if the same string is passed as an argument, I cannot check if the email address already exists in the table . What is a viable, but secure way to encrypt **and** check if the email address exists in the table ?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990827/checking-for-double-email-addresses-which-are-encrypted-in-the-database) involving the use of `hash` might be helpful?

Comment: ^ one really important thing to bear in mind with that ... make **sure** you lowercase the email addresses before encrypting them and storing them in the database (and lowercase the email for the comparison); people are really inconsistent with case in emails as I found out the hard way!

Comment: Heh - I pretty much asked this same question almost 4 years ago it seems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020238/user-lookup-on-encrypted-database-fields

Comment: Hashing seems to be the way to go . Is using the `SHA-256` algorithm with php's built in `hash` function a good idea or is there an even better way to hash?

Comment: You could use `BLOB` data in the database and store the email using MySQL's in-built `AES_ENCRYPT()` function. Then when you need to look up the email address you can do `WHERE AES_ENCRYPT(:email, :key) = user.email` ... where `:email` is the email address from your form and `:key` is the encryption key you're using (could be anything, set in a *config.php* file if you like as long as it's outside your document root).

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Indexing Encrypted Information](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#index-encrypted-information) in our paper on secure data encryption in PHP:

> An uncommon problem that many companies encounter is, "How can we encrypt information in a database and still index it for fast retrieval?" For example, if you need to be able to retrieve patient records by social security number in a health care application.
>
> If you have millions of records, decrypting each record one-by-one to perform a simple record lookup would be expensive for both the application and the database server. And storing such a sensitive record is a no-go (unless you enjoy apologizing to your customers and offering them one year of free identity theft protection).
>
> Instead, create a **blind index** of this information for indexing purposes. First, encrypt the information and store it in one field (say: `ssn`). Then, store a separate HMAC of the plaintext with a separate key in another field (e.g. `ssn_lookup`) and create the database index on the second field. (This idea was proposed in an [MSDN blog post by Raul Garcia](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/03/11/549754.aspx). If you are developing a .NET / SQL Server solution to this problem, Raul's blog post is probably more relevant.)
>
> The key for HMAC indexing purposes should be only available to the application server that needs to query the database, which should be on separate hardware, and never checked into version control.

Note that this only allows exact searches, not partial searches.

```
public function getAccountByEmail($email)
{
    $search = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE email_lookup = ?")
        ->execute([
            hash_hmac('sha256', $email, $this->searchKeys['email'])
        ])
        ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $search;
}
```